Test for presence of peak in time
I have RNA-Seq counts data for many genes, which is typically modeled with Negative Binomial, measured along time. I want to find which genes have a "peak" pattern.
An approach that is used with this type of data is GAMs with Negative Binomial family. However, it captures different patterns of genes varying with time. For example, here I am interested in gene_2, which peaks around a particular time point, but I'm not interested in gene_1: although it changes with time, it's not a peak-like pattern. Both have a significant p-value from the GAM fit.

Of course, I have thousands of genes to test in many circumstances, hence a few tens of thousands of tests, roughly one third of them I expect to be significant. I do not know a priori the exact shape of the impulse, maybe sometimes it's a bit wider or narrower.
Question: how can I test for genes with such an "impulse" shape? The null shape could be either genes that are constant in time, or genes that vary without peaking (like gene_1).
Ideas:
I first thought of adapting the spline basis used in mgcv::gam for the fitting, but could not find a suitable approach, nor could I find a smoother with a prior on the shape.
I also considered using a GLM to fit a second and third degree polynomial and compare their AIC (i.e. do we "need" a third degree), but in both cases the AIC decreases with a 3rd degree and I'm not sure of a better way to do this comparison.
Maybe another way could be some form of goodness-of-fit, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Compute the Wasserstein distance to a simulated "peaky" shape?
A last idea could be to cluster the fitted curves and identify the correct clusters (e.g. with {funHDDC}), I haven't explored that idea yet.

You may be able to compute the 1st derivatives of the estimated smooth functions and filter for those genes that have a characteristic pattern where all derivatives are positive up to a point, then they plateau, then they are all negative. This would signal a 'peak' like you've described

That is an interesting approach, but I have trouble seeing how to make it into a test, with some kind of p-value or test statistics that I could threshold or classify on.

You can compute derivatives with uncertainty estimates (a credible interval on the derivative) and only identify a peak where the derivative is positive, 0, then negative, where the positive and negative parts have derivatives whose credible intervals exclude 0. You really shouldn't use p values as you are implying - you probably shouldn't use the credible intervals like I propose either; but we could do a simultaneous interval on the derivative. Even then, you're going to be rejecting/accepting on basis of a p value. Better to reject/accept on basis of magnitude of or presence of peak.

Thank you to both of you. Following your suggestions I've been looking more at the peak detection aspect, and I think it's been going somewhere (working directly on the fitted curve I have something quite smooth that works well in of-the-shelf peak detection packages, then I can check other characteristics like peak width). Your comments are also reassuring that I'm not missing some obvious way to penalize the GAM splines.
